# Executing MySQL Queries and Creating Instances several Times within Loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have an Web Application that requires `SELECT` and `INSERT` Querying to MySQL database and Instantiating a PHP class using `new` operator almost more that thousand times within a loop. May be there are alternatives to my present logic, but my point is that is there any harm if I carry on this logic?. I don't bother about the time complexity associated with the algorithm presently but **worrying much about if anything goes wrong during transaction or memory usage. I am giving the piece of code for reference

```
$stm_const = "select ce.TIMETAKEN, qm.QMATTER as STRING1, ce.SMATTER as STRING2 from  w_clkexam ce, clkmst cm, qsmst qm where ce.QID=qm.QID and cm.ROLLNO=ce.ROLLNO";

for ($c=0; $c < count($rollnos); $c++) {
$stm3 =$stm_const." "."and ce.ROLLNO='$rollnos[$c]'";
$qry3 = mysql_query($stm3) or die("ERROR 3:".mysql_error());
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($qry3)) {
    echo $string1=$row1['STRING1'];
    echo $string2=$row1['STRING2'];

    $phpCompareStrings=new PhpCompareStrings($string2, $string1);
    $percent=$phpCompareStrings->getSimilarityPercentage();
    $percent2=$phpCompareStrings->getDifferencePercentage();
    echo '$string1 and $string2 are '.$percent.'% similar and '.$percent2.'%  differnt<br/>';
    }// end while
}// end for
```

Please help, I am waiting for opinions from you so that I can move further. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code samples? Also, have you thought about trying out a [singleton approach pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?

Comment: Code sample, yes.  Singleton, NO!

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking the app with sample data? Are you currently running into any problem?

Comment: Hi JohnP yes you have got my problem. Actually, as described above, I am trying to fetch data from database one by one and analyzing the data using a class within a same loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem there. You just get all the rows from database and for each row compare the strings. As you assign the object to the same variable each time, the old object is destroyed before the new object is created. So you have only one instance of the object in memory at all times. The question is what you want to do with the results? Only print them as in your example, or to store the results for further processing?

Anyway, I think it is not possible to optimize your code without modifying the class. If you are using [this class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6220-PHP-Compares-strings-to-determine-similarity-level.html), you can try to modify it so that it can accept multiple strings. Using this, you can create only 1 instance of the class and you avoid destroying/creating the object for every row. It will save you some CPU time, but not memory (as at all times, only 1 instance of the class is active).

Untested modification below:
Modify this function inside the class:

```
  function __construct($str1,$str2){
        $str1=trim($str1);
        $str2=trim($str2);
        if($str1==""){ trigger_error("First parameter can not be left blank", E_USER_ERROR); }
        elseif($str2==""){ trigger_error("Second parameter can not be left blank", E_USER_ERROR); }
        else{
            $this->str1=$str1;
            $this->str2=$str2;
            $this->arr1=explode(" ",$str1);
            $this->arr2=explode(" ",$str2);
        }
    }
```

To these 2 functions:

```
  function init($str1,$str2){
        $str1=trim($str1);
        $str2=trim($str2);
        if($str1==""){ trigger_error("First parameter can not be left blank", E_USER_ERROR); }
        elseif($str2==""){ trigger_error("Second parameter can not be left blank", E_USER_ERROR); }
        else{
            $this->str1=$str1;
            $this->str2=$str2;
            $this->arr1=explode(" ",$str1);
            $this->arr2=explode(" ",$str2);
        }
    }

  function __construct($str1,$str2){ $this->init($str1,$str2); }
```

Then create the object outside the loop and only call `$phpCompareStrings->init($string2,$string1)` inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks I used the code suggested by you and it's working fine. As you asked what is the ultimate goal, I am going to update the results into database for further reference.